# Retirar espaço em branco no select (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de retirar o espaço em branco dos registros retornados no select.

por exemplo tenho a tabela BAIRRO
com os registros
'Bela Vista'
'Amazonas'
' Areão'

mas quando faço

'''SELECT  id FROM BAIRRO WHERE NOME LIKE 'Areao' ;'''

ele nao retorna o id justamente por causa do espaço antes da palavra areao

Entao gostaria de saber se existe algum jeito de tirar esse espaço sem ter que alterar todos os registros da tabela

Answer (score 2):

Utilize a função TRIM:

```
SELECT id FROM BAIRRO WHERE TRIM(NOME) LIKE 'Areao' ;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim

Comment: Deu certo ! Muito obrigado!